# Why is this SQLite query failing in the first sintax but not the second?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working in Python 3.6 with the sqlite3 module. Id[0] is an integer.

This query

```
cursorObj.execute(
"SELECT Quality FROM MovieFiles WHERE MovieId={}".format(Id[0])
)
```

works fine and returns the expected selection.

The same query written like this

`cursorObj.execute( """SELECT Quality FROM MovieFiles WHERE MovieId=(?)""",(Id[0]), )`

produces a ValueType Error `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`

So I coerce the value into a string

```
string = str(Id[0])
cursorObj.execute(
"""SELECT Quality FROM MovieFiles WHERE MovieId=(?)""",(string),
)
```

and I get this `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.`

Answer (score 0):

To pass a tuple of one element, the comma needs to be inside parentheses: `(Id[0],)`

```py
cursorObj.execute("SELECT Quality FROM MovieFiles WHERE MovieId = ?", (Id[0],) )
```

Alternatively, cast to a list:

```py
cursorObj.execute("SELECT Quality FROM MovieFiles WHERE MovieId= ?", [Id[0]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I was in the process of reading the documentation and not just skimming over it and I realized that, it has to be a tuple, even if it is a single value https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Correct and true of general PEP 249 standard (beyond `sqlite3` but all DB-APIs): [execute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14): *Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation...*